# I want to compare 2 columns from differnt sheet using array and index in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to macro need a solution for my requirement. 
I want to compare 2 columns in 2 different sheets of the same workbook if the value matches then want to copy and paste data from sheet1 values(Column 3,4 and 5)  to sheet2(Column 3,4,5)

Currently, my code is not getting me the result, please help

```
Sub oldtonew()
  Dim Oldoutcome(1000) As Variant
  Dim newoutcome(1000) As Variant
  Dim I As Integer
  Dim PA1(1000) As String
  Dim PA2(1000) As String
  Dim PA3(1000) As String
  Dim AR(1000) As Variant
  Searchrow = 2
  Sheets("old").Select
  newoutcome(Searchrow) = "Architectural Model"
  'ActiveSheet.Range("S" & Searchrow).Value

   Do Until ActiveSheet.Range("AK" & Searchrow) = ""
     Oldoutcome(Searchrow) = ActiveSheet.Range("AK" & Searchrow).Value
     AR(Searchrow) = ActiveSheet.Range("X" & Searchrow).Value
     PA1(Searchrow) = ActiveSheet.Range("AR" & Searchrow).Value
     PA2(Searchrow) = ActiveSheet.Range("AS" & Searchrow).Value
     PA3(Searchrow) = ActiveSheet.Range("AT" & Searchrow).Value
     If InStr(Oldoutcome(Searchrow), newoutcome(Searchrow)) > 1 Then
       ActiveSheet.Range("Y" & Searchrow).Value = AR(Searchrow)
       ActiveSheet.Range("Z" & Searchrow).Value = PA1(Searchrow)
       ActiveSheet.Range("AA" & Searchrow).Value = PA2(Searchrow)
       ActiveSheet.Range("AB" & Searchrow).Value = PA3(Searchrow)
     End If
     Searchrow = Searchrow + 1
   Loop

   Sheets("Assessment").Select
   Do Until ActiveSheet.Range("S" & Searchrow) = ""
     ActiveSheet.Range("Y" & Searchrow).Value = AR(Index)
     ActiveSheet.Range("Z" & Searchrow).Value = PA1(Index)
     ActiveSheet.Range("AA" & Searchrow).Value = PA2(Index)
     ActiveSheet.Range("AB" & Searchrow).Value = PA3(Index)
     End If
     Searchrow = Searchrow + 1
   Loop
 End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example?* ([I downvoted because there is no code](//idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)) / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Could you elaborate on *my code is not getting me the result* - do you get some unwanted result, error or something else happens? In last loop you have `End If`, but there's no corresponding `If`

Comment: Requirement - I want to compare Column A in sheet1 with Column A in sheet2 and Column B Sheet1 with Column B in sheet 2. if the value matches then i have to paste Sheet 2's Column D, E, F, G to Sheet 1 column D, E, F, G